# How to add a header (that consists of thousands of names) to a pandas dataFrame

Tags: pandas, header

I have a data frame with 100 rows and 26000 columns and it already has header.
But how can I add an additional header that says "XXXX" to each of these 26000 columns?

I know that I can do something like this. But is there any other easy way?

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename", sep='\t', names = ["XXXX", "XXXX", "XXXX", "XXXX", ..........(26995 times)........, "XXXX"])
```

Comment: You can use `names = ["XXXX"] * 26000` but if use `0.19.1` also cannot get duplicates columns names

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Are you asking how to substitute all the column names to be the same or you want to add a new level of columns in addition to the the existing columns?

Comment: new column to the existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""a;b;c;d
1;11;12;1
1;14;15;3
"""
#after testing replace StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";")
print (df)
   a   b   c  d
0  1  11  12  1
1  1  14  15  3

#add level to columns - get multiindex
new_cols = list(zip(df.columns, ['XXX'] * len(df.columns)))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)
print (df)
    a   b   c   d
  XXX XXX XXX XXX
0   1  11  12   1
1   1  14  15   3
```

---

```
new_cols = list(zip( ['XXX'] * len(df.columns), df.columns))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)
print (df)
  XXX           
    a   b   c  d
0   1  11  12  1
1   1  14  15  3

#temporary change value of multi_sparse
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)

  XXX XXX XXX XXX
    a   b   c   d
0   1  11  12   1
1   1  14  15   3
```

Comment: looks great, is it possible to add it as a 1st row instead of 2nd ?

Comment: I think there is some inconsistency in the second code. It doesn't add XXX on top of b, c and d. Could you please check. But it seems fine other than that. Have a great day as well :)

Comment: It is right, because by default value of `display.multi_sparse` is True - see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options) - `display.multi_sparse`  `True`  `Sparsify MultiIndex display (don’t display repeated elements in outer levels within groups)`

Comment: Great description. I understand much better now. thanks!!